# weird behaviour when saving template

Tags: templates

i just had fresh installation EE 2.4
and i worked with this copy on other hosting and its working charm
now when i go to Template Manager
trying to update Template in Template group 
it redirect me to

http://mydomain.com/admin.php?S=aa84c50e6774e629815f32e012534c99c1b24f6c&D=cp&C=design&M=update_template&tgpref=1

and no changes save

and when i remove wrapping html  tag
it work and save

any idea ??

Comment: "**fresh** installation EE **2.4**"?? Marty,  it is almost Jan 2015, not Jan 2012. Did you try to update it to last version 2.9.2?  What do you mean by "wrapping html tag"?

Comment: When i use <html> tag it redirect me on 404 page when i click update or update and finish

Comment: I updated to 2.9.2 the same problem :(

Comment: can you update your question with your entire template code?

Comment: Its just html empty page simple it doesnt allow me to save with <html> tag .. when j remove it update button works and saves